# Why am I getting the same data in PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, discord.py, psycopg2

I am writing a bot discord. I need to create a top function that will display the top users on the server, and here is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def top(ctx):
    """The top function returns a list of the top 10
members of the server by quantity xp.
    """
    emb = discord.Embed(title="Топ 10 участников сервера:")
    cursor.execute(f"""SELECT name, xp FROM users ORDER BY xp DESC LIMIT 10;""")
    top_users = cursor.fetchall()
    counter = 0
    for row in top_users:
        counter += 1
        emb.add_field(
            name=f"{counter}. {row[0]}",
            value=f"Опыт: {row[1]}XP",
            inline=False
        )
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

But instead of data from different users, I get data from one user:

```
[('Poliak228#8755', 100), ('Poliak228#8755', 100), ('Poliak228#8755', 100), ('Poliak228#8755', 100), ('Poliak228#8755', 100), ('Poliak228#8755', 100), ('Poliak228#8755', 100), ('Poliak228#8755', 100), ('Poliak228#8755', 100), ('Poliak228#8755', 100)]
```

I checked and there were no identical records in the database. So why is this happening?

Comment: That data doesn't look like the values you're creating.  Where's the counter?  Where's the "XP"?

Comment: Maybe you have a lot of duplicate elements in your database?

Comment: No, I cheked it.

Comment: Try to use `top_users = cursor.execute(f"""SELECT name, xp FROM users ORDER BY xp DESC LIMIT 10;""").fetchall()`.

Comment: I tried this but got this error: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetchall'`

Comment: you could `SELECT` also `ID` (if you have it in rows) to see which rows give this results.

Comment: In the client `psql` run `SELECT name, xp FROM users ORDER BY xp DESC LIMIT 10;` and see what you get? I'm betting it is what you show in the list of tuples. I'm guessing  you want something more like `SELECT distinct on(name, xp) name, xp FROM users ORDER BY xp DESC LIMIT 10;`.